# C++ Multi-dimensional Array with sum for each row and column

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, sum

A couple of days ago I re-start coding.  This time with C++ and not Java. I have book full of lessons. By one I'm stuck now since two days. Maybe someone here can give me some advices.

The lesson starts with this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // ein 2-dim. Array erstellen
    int Zeile, Spalte;
    int Tab[5][4];

    for (Zeile = 0; Zeile <= 4; Zeile++)
    {
        for (Spalte = 0; Spalte <= 3; Spalte++)
        {
            Tab[Zeile][Spalte] = 0;
        }            
    }

    // 2-dim. Array mit Zufallszahlen füllen
    for (Zeile = 0; Zeile <= 4; Zeile++)
    {
        for (Spalte = 0; Spalte <= 3; Spalte++)
        {
            Tab[Zeile][Spalte] = rand() % 10 + 1;
        }        
    }

    // Ausgabe des 2-dim. Arrays
    for (Zeile = 0; Zeile <= 4; Zeile++)
    {
        for (Spalte = 0; Spalte <= 3; Spalte++)
        {
            cout << setw(8) << Tab[Zeile][Spalte];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code I get something like this:

6   3   5   1

7   4   4   2

3   3   3   3

1   2   3   4

6   7   7   7

Now I should create a new row and a new column filled with the SUM of each row and each column. So it should look like this:

6   3   5   1   15

7   4   4   2   17

3   3   3   3   12

1   2   3   4   10

6   7   7   7   27

23 19  22  17   81

The only thing I got looks like this:

```
int main()
{
    // ein 2-dim. Array erstellen
    int Zeile, Spalte, Spaltensumme, Zeilesumme;
    int Tab[5][4];

    for (Zeile = 0; Zeile <= 4; Zeile++)
    {
        for (Spalte = 0; Spalte <= 3; Spalte++)
        {
            Tab[Zeile][Spalte] = 0;
        }            
    }

    // 2-dim. Array mit Zufallszahlen füllen
    for (Zeile = 0; Zeile <= 4; Zeile++)
    {
        for (Spalte = 0; Spalte <= 3; Spalte++)
        {
            Tab[Zeile][Spalte] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            
            // Finden der Spaltensumme 
            for (Zeile = 0; Zeile < 4; ++Zeile)
            {
                for (Spalte = 0; Spalte <= 3; ++Spalte)
                {
                    Spaltensumme = Spaltensumme + Tab[Zeile][Spalte];
                }
            }

            // Finden der Zeilensumme 
            for (Zeile = 0; Zeile < 4; ++Zeile)
            {
                for (Spalte = 0; Spalte <= 3; ++Spalte)
                {
                    Zeilesumme = Zeilesumme + Tab[Spalte][Zeile];
                }
            }
        }        
    }

    // Ausgabe des 2-dim. Arrays
    for (Zeile = 0; Zeile <= 4; Zeile++)
    {
        for (Spalte = 0; Spalte <= 3; Spalte++)
        {
            cout << setw(8) << Tab[Zeile][Spalte];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry that the comments are in German. I'm coding in the same style like the book.
I know my code doesn't work and it's getting worse by each hour. Maybe someone can help me out before I'm going to get crazy. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main idea is to add an extra row and column so that we can store the sum as we fill up the matrix with random numbers. I have tried to keep as much as possible of your code intact. I have added comments wherever the code needs a change.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // ein 2-dim. Array erstellen
    int Zeile, Spalte;
    int Tab[6][5]; //increase number of columns and rows by 1 here to store the sum

    for (Zeile = 0; Zeile <= 5; Zeile++)//updated the bound of Zeile
    {
        for (Spalte = 0; Spalte <= 4; Spalte++)//updated the bound of Spalte
        {
            Tab[Zeile][Spalte] = 0;
        }            
    }
    
    // 2-dim. Array mit Zufallszahlen füllen
    for (Zeile = 0; Zeile <= 4; Zeile++)
    {
        for (Spalte = 0; Spalte <= 3; Spalte++)
        {
            Tab[Zeile][Spalte] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            Tab[Zeile][4] += Tab[Zeile][Spalte]; // add to row sum 
            Tab[5][Spalte] += Tab[Zeile][Spalte]; // add to column sum
            Tab[5][4] += Tab[Zeile][Spalte]; //lowest-rightmost sum element
        }        
    }
    
    // Ausgabe des 2-dim. Arrays
    for (Zeile = 0; Zeile <= 5; Zeile++) //updated the bound of Zeile
    {
        for (Spalte = 0; Spalte <= 4; Spalte++) //updated the bound of Spalte
        {
            cout << setw(8) << Tab[Zeile][Spalte];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```